# Table Name for @Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have one class as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
public class DynamicTemplate {
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @ElementCollection
    Set<TemplateAttributes> attributes;

    //setters and getters
```

and another table is like below

```
@Table(name = "attribute")
@Embeddable
public class TemplateAttributes {
    private String name;
    private Double normalLow;
```

In the database @Embeddable table is being created with **template_attributes** name rather than  provided name **attribute**

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the CollectionTable-Annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
public class DynamicTemplate {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "attribute")
    Set<TemplateAttributes> attributes;
   
    ...
}


@Embeddable
public class TemplateAttributes {
    private String name;
    private Double normalLow;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your schema does not make much sense.

*@Embeddable* marks that this object is not to be mapped as a table, but rather a set of properties that go/are embedded into another entities/tables (in fact, you may use it for several properties at different entities).

If *DynamicTemplate* had an *TemplateAttributes attribute;* property, you would have *name* and *normalLow* columns in the table *template*. But you cannot have a set of values as columns in the same table.

What you need is to either make *TemplateAttributes* an entity, or, if you need to reuse *TemplateAttributes*, create a new entity that has an id and a *TemplateAttributes* property and have a set of them.